# How to make an or statement in a firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database in firebase and have the following query

`query(ref(database, 'message/'), orderByChild('ReceiverID'), equalTo("Username"))`

But I want to create the following query

`query(ref(database, 'message/'), orderByChild('ReceiverID'), equalTo("Username") or orderByChild('SenderID'), equalTo("Username"))`

Comment: Logical OR conditions are not supported.  You will have to perform two queries and combine the results.

Comment: Yeah ok that adds up, need to break away from the SQL way of thinking, thanks for the help and suggestion.

Comment: I find it easiest to think of Firebase Realtime Database results as requesting a single slice of the child nodes under consideration. That's why some AND-type condition are possible (by creating an extra property combining the values), but OR-type conditions aren't (as that'd result in multiple slices).

Comment: Yes for a "and" statement for the condition would be query(ref(database, 'message/'),orderByChild('ReceiverID'), equalTo("Username"), orderByChild('SenderID'), equalTo("Username"))